# Global Variables not updating/remain undefined

Tags: python

Here's some snippets of code:

```
global chairs
chairs = [[0 for column in range(cols)] for row in range(rows)]                       
ff.write('\n'.join([''.join(['{:4}'.format(item) for item in row]) 
for row in chairs]))
```

Take note that the code snippet above is in an if statement separate from the one below, but they are indented at the same level. Now, I use the variable *chairs* in another if statement outside of where I declared it to be global.

```
if chairs[coltake-1][rowtake-1]==0:
```

I'm pretty sure I followed the declaration syntax correctly, but why doesn't the variable *chairs* update? None of my code is in functions, by the way.

Comment: `global` is only meaningful inside a function definition. What, exactly, are the two contexts where `chairs` is being used. Complete, verifiable example, please.

Comment: how do i get the variable chairs to update if i don't use a function? i've tried placing it outside the ifs and the loops and it still doesn't update :(

Comment: Let me rephrase: do you *have* a function? If so, show it. Otherwise, `global` isn't doing anything for you.

Comment: Oopsie. I am not using any functions. Do you have any suggestions on how I could get chairs to still update? I'm new to python so sorry for the dumb questions!

Comment: You're really not giving us much to work with.  What is the expected output? What is the actual output? Why are you using the term "update" when you've presented only one assignment?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example